# Why do the JOptionpanes not appear?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, joptionpane

I have created a JCombobox and want that when a certain item is selected in the box, the respective ConfirmDialogs/MessageDialogs appear. What have I done wrong? Because unfortunately nothing happens when I click on my button "okBtn" :/
I have already tried a lot of things, but unfortunately I am still stuck and would appreciate any help (:
My Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class MusicGenre extends JFrame {

    String MusicGenre[] = {"Lo-Fi", "Future-House", "Deep-House", "Anderes"};

    public MusicGenre() {

        setTitle("Genre-Auswahl");
        setSize(250, 250);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 2));

        JLabel frage = new JLabel("An welches Genre denkst du?");
        panel.add(frage);

        JComboBox genreAuswahl = new JComboBox(MusicGenre);
        panel.add(genreAuswahl);

        JButton okBtn = new JButton("Okay");
        okBtn.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        okBtn.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        okBtn.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
        okBtn.setOpaque(true);

        JButton backBtn = new JButton("Zurück");
        backBtn.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        backBtn.setForeground(Color.RED);
        backBtn.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
        backBtn.setOpaque(true);


        okBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

               if (genreAuswahl.equals("Lo-Fi")){
                   int lofi = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Produzierst du selber Musik?");
                   if (lofi == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Meine Idee: Erstelle einen Lo-Fi Beat");
                       System.exit(0);
                   }else {
                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Meine Idee: Hör dir Lo-Fi an");
                       System.exit(0);
                   }
                   if (genreAuswahl.equals("Future-House")){
                       int fh = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Produzierst du selber Musik?");
                       if (fh == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Meine Idee: Erstelle einen Future-House Beat");
                       }else {
                           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Meine Idee: Hör dir Future-House an");
                       }
                       if (genreAuswahl.equals("Deep-House")){
                           int dh = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Produzierst du selber Musik?");
                           if (dh == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Meine Idee: Erstelle einen Deep-House Beat");
                           }else {
                               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Meine Idee: Hör dir Deep-House an");
                           }
                           if (genreAuswahl.equals("Anderes")){
                               int other = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Produzierst du selber Musik?");
                               if (other == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Meine Idee: Erstelle Musik deiner Wahl");
                               }else {
                                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hör dir Musik deiner Wahl an");
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
            }
        });


        backBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                dispose();
            }
        });

        panel.add(okBtn);
        panel.add(backBtn);

        add(panel);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: If my solution worked for you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer and close the question. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your if statement, instead of comparing a JComboBox object with a string like you do in your code as follows:

`genreAuswahl.equals("Lo-Fi")`

Compare the actual selected item (which is a String object):

`genreAuswhal.getSelectedItem().equals("Lo-Fi")`

Do this for other if controls too and your code should work as expected. I tried it locally and worked for me.

The reason any of your if statements won't work is that the JComboBox can never be equal to a String object.